# Can the eigenvalue for a quantum mechanical operator be zero?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

Can the eigenvalue for a quantum mechanical operator be zero?

Comment: yes it could be, here you could find a satisfying answer [link](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-have-an-eigenvalue-of-0-for-an-operator-in-quantum-mechanics-If-so-what-does-that-mean-about-the-eigenvalue-of-the-operator)

Comment: The question is _way_ broader than you seem to think; you might want to be more specific. As it stands now, the answer is "yes", but it is a really useless "yes", about the same level as if you were asking _"can **a difference** of two numbers be zero"_. Sure it can; so what?

Answer (score 3):

$S_z$ (spin along the z-axis) is a QM operator, and it frequently is zero - such as in closed-shell molecules.

Also note that the zero energy point of quantum mechanics can be defined in more than one way: some quantum chemistry programs use "all electrons and nuclei at infinite separation", whereas some solid state programs used "neutral atoms at infinite separation". Nevertheless, they evaluate the total energy.